# search bar using cakephp

Tags: database, cakephp-3.0, searchbar

I'm new when it comes to work with CakePHP. I'm facing a problem that is bothering me since i started doing it. I got a form with an input and when a person types in what he/she wants (it is a classified website where you can search for something that you'd like to buy eg. a blue pen) it shows the page that refers to the desired object. For example. if i type in 'blue pen', it retrieves all the data that i have in my database related to the blue pen.
Hope you can help me, there is my code:

index.ctp

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Location', array('type' => 'get'));
    echo $this->Form->input('Find');
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

and my ArticlesController

```
public function search() {
    $obj = '';
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
       $obj  = $this->data['Location']['Procurar'];
       $opts  = array(
           'conditions' => array('Location.Procurar' => $obj)
       );
    }
    $this->set('obj', $obj); // so the keyword is saved. Can also get it via $this->data
 }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to search a database for the "blue pen" information?  What have you tried so far?  Do you know what kind of database you're using to store this information?